# jQuery Select2 multi-value select with DJango/Python

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, jquery-select2

Currently, I'm using jQuery/Select2 in my project with DJango/Python. How can get all the values that have been selected? I tried `form.cleaned_data['field']` but I only get a single value. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

In your view you can simply use

```
data = request.POST.getlist("field")
```

Comment: the problem with that workaround is that your input is not validated nor sanitised, if needed. Which should be always a concern.